# Replace with random number between range

Tags: r

**Problem**: In VAR how can I replace every value of 1 with a random number between 1.1 and 7.1 and every value of 2 with a random number between 7.2 and 10.1?

```
i = seq(1,2,by = 1)

j = c(0.30,0.70)

VAR = sample(i, size = 100, replace = TRUE, prob = j)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `runif` to generate random numbers between min and max value.

```
VAR[VAR == 1] <- runif(sum(VAR == 1), 1.1, 7.1)
VAR[VAR == 2] <- runif(sum(VAR == 2), 7.2, 10.1)
```